# Trying to append a list in its own list... what happens?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

```
list1 = ['inception', 'dream', 'movie']
list2 = list1
list1.append(list2)
list1
```

If I run this code on the terminal,

```
['inception', 'dream', 'movie',[...]]
```

is the output. What happens if I append a list in its own list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

List elements are just references to other Python values. You've stored a reference to the list itself inside the list.

The list representation reflects this; instead of throwing an error or filling your terminal with endlessly nested representations of the same list, Python shows `[...]` to indicate a recursive structure.

The same applies to dictionaries:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d['d'] = d
>>> d
{'d': {...}}
```

or any mix of standard container types. It is not limited to just one level or a single reference either:

```
>>> l = ['foo', 'bar', {}]
>>> l[-1]['spam'] = l
>>> l[-1]['eggs'] = l
>>> l
['foo', 'bar', {'eggs': [...], 'spam': [...]}]
```

The `[...]` or `{...}` reference just indicates that printing the contents would lead to recursion.